# The farther I move my character, the more its projectiles fire in the wrong direction

Tags: unity, 2d, projectile-physics

I'm making a top down shooter, and the movement is working fine.

However, I'm having trouble getting my Fire function to work correctly. When I run the game, it kind of fires in the right direction, but the more I move, the more off the shooting becomes. Anyone have any idea why?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float _horizontalInput = 0;
    private float _verticalInput = 0;

    public int movementSpeed = 2;
    public int rotationSpeed = 2;

    Rigidbody2D rb2d;

    float coolDown = 0;

    public Rigidbody2D bulletPrefab;
    public float attackSpeed = 0.5f;
    public float bulletSpeed = 500;
    public float yValue = 1f; // Used to make it look like it's shot from the gun itself (offset)
    public float xValue = 1f; // Same as above

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {

        MovePlayer();
        RotatePlayer();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        GetPlayerInput();

        // Determines if the player can fire
        if (Time.time >= coolDown)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                Fire();
            }
        }
    }

    private void GetPlayerInput()
    {
        _horizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        _verticalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        

    }

    public void MovePlayer()
    {
        rb2d.velocity = transform.right * Mathf.Clamp01(_verticalInput) * movementSpeed;
    }

    private void RotatePlayer()
    {
        float rotation = -_horizontalInput * rotationSpeed;
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * rotation);
    }

    private void Fire()
    {
        Rigidbody2D bPrefab = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, new Vector3(transform.position.x + xValue, transform.position.y + yValue, transform.position.z), transform.rotation) as Rigidbody2D;

        bPrefab.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(transform.position * bulletSpeed);
        coolDown = Time.time + attackSpeed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two mistakes on this line:

```
bPrefab.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(transform.position * bulletSpeed);
```

1. You're passing a *position* where it looks like you want to pass a *direction*.

   Try `transform.right` to fire along the object's x (red) axis, or `transform.up` to fire along the object's y (green) axis. If you need a different direction, edit your question to include a diagram.
2. You're passing a *velocity* to a function that expects a *force*.

   Try `Vector2 velocity = transform.right * bulletSpeed;` then either...

   `bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = velocity;`

   or

   ```
   var body = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
   body.AddForce(body.mass * velocity, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
   ```

Also, don't name your instance variable `bPrefab` with "prefab" in the name - it's *not* a prefab, it's an *instance of* the prefab, which is a different object. Misleading variable names eventually come back to bite us in confusion down the line, so keep them well-matched to their actual meaning.

Comment: My character is a tank the can rotate 360 degrees. I'm trying to make the bullet spawn whichever way the character is facing and fire in that direction if that helps at all

Comment: This depends on how you've set up your character. If the barrel points along the local x+ (red) axis, then you want `transform.right`. If it points along the local y+ (green) axis, then you want `transform.up`. If you need something else, I'll repeat my request to add a diagram to your question illustrating what you need.

Comment: transform.right worked! Thank you so much